# How did anyone not notice what Lara Lor-Van was carrying

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

How did anyone not notice that Lara Lor-Van was carrying a baby for a full term? Considering that Kryptonians [prohibited](http://dccomicsextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Genesis_Chamber) cross breeding,

> Thousands of years ago, the Kryptonian law council prohibited
>   scientists from crossbreeding Kryptonians and fauna after
>   monstrosities were created.
>
> The Genesis Chamber was created on the planet Krypton to store the
>   Growth Codex and all the unborn Kryptonian embryos that would populate
>   future Kryptonian society. It was submerged in amniotic fluid, where
>   Aquabots were used to control and maintain the chamber, so no
>   Kryptonians could enter or contaminate the birthing process.

Did Kal El , hide here for the whole term?
And it seems she was at least [pretty important](http://dccomicsextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Legislation_Chamber) to Krypton, as she was [to be considered one of the brightest minds on Krypton](http://dccomicsextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Lara_Lor-Van), so it would be pretty hard to hide her. So it would be pretty hard to do that one would think?

Comment: The part about cross-breeding here seems irrelevant, as Kal-El was a pure-breed Kryptonian.

Comment: @KutuluMike, wasn't cross breeding meant to signify army types with intellectual types of the same race (Kryptonians)?

Comment: Asked and answered on [another stack](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/12471/laras-pregnancy-in-man-of-steel). The best guess is that she did what all pregnant teenagers do to hide it from their friends/parents/school. She restricted her activities and wore big frumpy jumpers. Everyone probably just thought she'd let herself go or discovered puddings.

Comment: no, the crossbreeding specifically meant breeding Kryptonians with non-Kyrptonians (like was done in *Dawn of Justice* to make Doomsday).

Comment: @Valorum, my bad, I was going to accept it.Sorry I had to make you post this.

Comment: @Valorum, I am guessing it would. I think I still have a few outstanding from you I need to accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the failure of her husband to convince the Council of Justice to stop mining the planetary core, Jor-El and Lara Lor-Van apparently isolated themselves, conducting scientific research, building an experimental pod and having a baby.

Given the rift between the Council and Jor-El, the ubiquity of [advanced tele-presence devices](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/superman/images/7/78/Kelex_MoS.png/revision/latest?cb=20131016043028) and her obvious need to hide her 'delicate condition' from her peers, the likelihood is that she simply withdrew from public life for a few months.

She certainly wasn't shy about wearing maternity-wear (as the concept art below shows) but one assumes this was to be worn inside the family's *citadel* and not outside.

[image]